# Al llamar a una función, se deja de leer el archivo (fread) - C

Tags: c, binary-files

Tengo dos archivos binarios:
"VENDEGAS.dat" que contiene a los vendedores (DNI, nombre y año de ingreso)
y
"ESALGAS.dat" que contiene ventas de vendedores (DNI, mes, importe y división)

El problema es que al no encontrar al vendedor del archivo "ESALGAS" registrado en "VENDEGAS" (línea 100, función "leerEsalgas"), pide que introduzcan el nombre, y al llamar a la función "cargarVendedor" (línea 104), deja de leer el archivo y finaliza el programa. En vez de esto, debería seguir con la lectura, y si encuentra a otro vendedor no registrado, pedir el nombre nuevamente...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CANTVEND 20

typedef struct{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int anio;
}TFecha;

typedef struct{
    int dni;
    char nomyap[51];
    int anio;
}TVendedor;

typedef struct{
    int dni;
    TFecha fechaVenta;
    float importe;
    char division[16];
}TVentas;

typedef struct{
    char nomyap[51];
    int cantMeses;
}TCapacitar;

FILE *pfVend, *pfEsal, *pfNuevos;

void leerVendegas(TVendedor[]);
void leerEsalgas(TVendedor[]);
void inicializarVendedores(TVendedor[]);
int buscarVendedor(TVendedor [], int);
void cargarVendedor(TVendedor [], TVentas);
void actualizarVendegas(TVendedor []);
void imprimirListado(TVendedor []);

int main(){
    TVendedor AVendedores[CANTVEND];
    inicializarVendedores(AVendedores);
    leerVendegas(AVendedores);
    leerEsalgas(AVendedores);
    actualizarVendegas(AVendedores);
    imprimirListado(AVendedores);
}

void inicializarVendedores(TVendedor AVendedores[]){
        for(int i=0; i<CANTVEND; i++){
        AVendedores[i].dni = 0;
        strcpy(AVendedores[i].nomyap, "");
        AVendedores[i].anio = 0;
    }
}

void leerVendegas(TVendedor AVendedores[]){
    pfVend = fopen("VENDEGAS.dat", "rb");
    if(pfVend == NULL){
        printf("\nERROR EN ARCHIVO VENDEGAS");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nVENDEDORES");
    printf("\n---------------------------");
    printf("\n%-8s %-20s %-4s", "DNI", "NOMBRE", "ANIO");

    // GUARDA EN EL ARRAY "AVendedores" LOS VENDEDORES ALMACENADOS EN EL ARCHIVO "VENDEGAS" 
    int cont = 0;
    TVendedor aux;
    fread(&aux, sizeof(TVendedor), 1, pfVend);
    while(!feof(pfVend)){
        printf("\n%d %-20s %d", aux.dni, aux.nomyap, aux.anio);
        AVendedores[cont] = aux;
        fread(&aux, sizeof(TVendedor), 1, pfVend);
        cont++;
    }
    fclose(pfVend);
}

void leerEsalgas(TVendedor AVendedores[]){

    printf("\n\nVENTAS");
    printf("\n---------------------------");
    printf("\n%-11s %-6s %-15s %-10s", "DNI", "MES", "IMPORTE", "DIVISION");

    pfEsal = fopen("ESALGAS.dat", "rb");
    if(pfEsal == NULL){
        printf("\nERROR EN ARCHIVO ESALGAS");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    // IMPRIME TODAS LAS VENTAS ALMACENADAS EN EL ARCHIVO "ESALGAS"
    TVentas aux;
    fread(&aux, sizeof(TVentas), 1, pfEsal);
    while(!feof(pfEsal)){
        // BUSCA EN EL ARRAY "AVendedores" SI EL VENDEDOR SE ENCUENTRA REGISTRADO
        int index = buscarVendedor(AVendedores, aux.dni);
        printf("\n%-11d %-6d $%-15.2f %-10s", aux.dni, aux.fechaVenta.mes,aux.importe, aux.division);
        // SI EL VENDEDOR NO ESTA REGISTRADO Y PERTENECE A LA DIVISION "GAS", PIDE QUE LO CARGUEN
        if(index == -1 && strcmpi(aux.division, "GAS") == 0){
            cargarVendedor(AVendedores, aux);
        }
        fread(&aux, sizeof(TVentas), 1, pfEsal);
    }
    fclose(pfEsal);
}

int buscarVendedor(TVendedor AVendedores[], int dni){
    int cont = 0;
    // BUSCA AL VENDEDOR EN EL ARRAY "AVendedores" Y RETORNA EL INDICE DE SU POSICION O -1 SI NO LO ENCUENTRA
    while(cont < CANTVEND){
        if(AVendedores[cont].dni == dni){
            return cont;
        }
        cont++;
    }
    return -1;
}

void cargarVendedor(TVendedor AVendedores[], TVentas aux){
    printf("\n---------------------------");
    printf("\nVendedor %d no encontrado en VENDEGAS", aux.dni);
    printf("\nIngrese nombre y apellido para completar el registro: ");
    // SE CREA AL NUEVO VENDEDOR TOMANDO LOS DATOS DE LA VENTA Y EL NOMBRE POR TECLADO
    TVendedor auxVendedor;
    fgets(auxVendedor.nomyap, 51, stdin);
    auxVendedor.nomyap[strlen(auxVendedor.nomyap)-1] = '\0';
    auxVendedor.anio = aux.fechaVenta.anio;
    auxVendedor.dni = aux.dni;
    int cont = 0;
    // BUSCA LA PRIMER POSICION DEL ARRAY "AVendedores" VACIA
    while( cont < CANTVEND ){
        if(AVendedores[cont].dni == 0){
            // GUARDA AL NUEVO VENDEDOR EN EL ARRAY
            AVendedores[cont] = auxVendedor;
            // GUARDA AL NUEVO VENDEDOR EN EL ARCHIVO "NUEVOS"
            pfNuevos = fopen("NUEVOS.dat", "ab");
            if(pfVend == NULL){
                printf("\nError archivo NUEVOS");
                system("pause");
                exit(1);
            }
            fwrite(&auxVendedor, sizeof(TVendedor), 1, pfVend);
            fclose(pfNuevos);
            printf("\nVendedor agregado con exito\n");
            return;
        }
        cont++;
    }
    printf("\nRegistro de vendedores lleno, imposible agregar otro.");
}

void actualizarVendegas(TVendedor AVendedores[]){
    pfVend = fopen("VENDEGAS.dat", "wb");
    if(pfVend == NULL){
        printf("\nError archivo VENDEGAS");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    int cont=0;
    // SOBREESCRIBE EL ARCHIVO "VENDEGAS" CON TODOS LOS VENDEDORES EN EL ARRAY "AVendedores"
    while (cont<CANTVEND){
        if(AVendedores[cont].dni!=0){
            fwrite(&AVendedores[cont], sizeof(TVendedor), 1, pfVend);
        }
        cont++;
    }
    fclose(pfEsal);
    printf("\n\n---------------------------");
    printf("\nVENDEGAS ACTUALIZADO");
    printf("\n---------------------------\n");
}

void imprimirListado(TVendedor AVendedores[]){
    printf("\nVENTAS POR MES SEGUN VENDEDOR");
    printf("\n---------------------------");
    printf("\n%-20s %-2s %-2s %-2s %-2s %-2s %-2s %-2s %-2s %-2s %-2s %-2s %-2s", "VENDEDOR/MES", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12");
    
    int cont = 0;
    while(cont < 20 && AVendedores[cont].dni != 0){
        pfEsal = fopen("ESALGAS.dat", "rb");
        if(pfEsal == NULL){
            printf("\nError archivo ESALGAS");
            system("pause");
            exit(1);
        }
        // INICIALIZA TODOS LOS MESES EN 'N'
        char meses[12];
        for(int i=0;i<12;i++){meses[i]='N';}
        printf("\n%-20s ", AVendedores[cont].nomyap);
        TVentas aux;
        fread(&aux, sizeof(TVentas), 1, pfEsal);
        while(!feof(pfEsal)){
            // SI EL DNI DE LA VENTA COINCIDE CON EL DNI DEL VENDEDOR, GUARDA 'S' EN EL MES DE LA VENTA
            if(aux.dni == AVendedores[cont].dni){
                meses[aux.fechaVenta.mes-1] = 'S';
            }
            fread(&aux, sizeof(TVentas), 1, pfEsal);
        }
        // IMPRIME LOS MESES
        for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
            printf("%-2c ", meses[i]);
        }
        fclose(pfEsal);
        cont++;
    }
}
```

[image: Print de la consola]

En la imagen se puede ver que me pide el nombre del primer vendedor no encontrado en el archivo "VENDEGAS" y finaliza el programa, sin embargo, luego debería pedirme el nombre del segundo vendedor no registrado y así sucesivamente si es que hay más...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en `cargarVendedor()`. Mezclas operaciones con el flujo `pfNuevos` y operaciones con el flujo `pfVend`.

Esto no pasaría si las declaraciones de los flujos eran internas a las funciones, en lugar de ser globales como lo has hecho.